# Consuming soap on Angular 4

Tags: angular, soap, angular-http

I'm trying to consume a soap ws in Angular4, i didn't find any good example, i've tried  "***autopulous-angular2-soap***" but i'm getting the error :

> WARNING in ./node_modules/autopulous-angular2-soap/soap.service.js
>   System.register is not supported by webpack.  @
>   ./src/app/app.module.ts 22:0-68  @ ./src/main.ts  @ multi
>   webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts

i've tried adding on my ***tsconfig.json*** :

> "module": "commonjs"

but it did not resolve the issue, someone has a good example of how to consume Soap web services on Angular 4, thank's in advance

Comment: What’s wrong with just following the soap protocol with the xml?

Comment: why not ? i just need a simple example so i can follow it step by step and integrate it in my app

Comment: can you try and then post your code with stack trace of what happened?